# Remove image in map that can't be fetch

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching data from an api and then use it in a map to display its content (description, images, name etc). The thing is that some of the images can't be fetch anymore (`404 Not found`) because the link is no longer available causing a blank space through the data I'm displaying. Is there a way to get over this dead link when I'm mapping through them ?

```js
data.meals.map((i, key) => {
   return(
    <MealCard key={key} title={i.strMeal} image={`${i.strMealThumb}/preview`} />
   )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a onError to your image element, and if it errors you could remove the element.

OR

Inversely you could load all your images first, and add a onLoad and add only the images which successfully load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-fallback

```
             <ReactImageFallback
                src="my-image.png"
                fallbackImage="my-backup.png"
                initialImage="loader.gif"
                alt="cool image should be here"
                className="my-image" />
```

In src you can show your image , If image link is broken then fallbackimage true.. You can set default image or none here.